# Question about corollary 2.1.6 in Cohen's Number Theory vol. 1.

Tags: number-theory, abelian-groups

Corollary 2.1.6.

Let $ V \in \mathbb{Z}^n $ be a column vector of $ n $ globally coprime integers. There exists an integral matrix $ A \in GL_n (\mathbb {Z}) $ ( in other words with determinant $1$ ) having $ V $ as first column.

Questions.1) Is it necessary to use the word globally?  If so what does the sentence mean without the word globally? 2) Shouldn't $ GL $ be replaced with $ SL $ because those are the matrices with determinant $1$?

[image: Picture of page containing corollary 2.1.6]

Comment: With determinant +1 or -1, it says

Comment: Of Course!  There should be a name for matrices with determinant +-1.

Comment: @ndroock1 People sometimes call them *unimodular*.

Comment: The term "globally" in this context is not standard, though at the same time there really is no conventional adjective in English for this concept for $n$-tuples. You usually say "relatively prime as an $n$-tuple." Or, for vectors, you call it a primitive vector. For a generalization of this result to Dedekind domains, see http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/ringtheory/primvector.pdf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first question:  If the proposition just said $n$ coprime integers, that would (or could) be taken to mean that each pair of integers $\{v_i,v_j\}|i \neq j$ is coprime ($\gcd(v_i,v_j) = 1$).  This is a much stronger condition than is required for the proposition (which is that there is no "global" divisor $d>1|d\in\Bbb{Z}$ dividing *every* $v_i$.

For the second part of the question, I agree that the wording would be clearer if he had used $SL_n(\Bbb{Z})$ because the way it reads now, it could be taken to mean that all "integral matrices" have the property that their determinant is $\pm 1$.  But I am reluctant to critique Cohen's wording because perhaps he had some good reason for saying it in this way, which I am just missing.

LATER EDIT: And in fact, all members of the integral matrix *group* over $\Bbb{Z}$ do have determinant $\pm 1$. And $SL_n(\Bbb{Z})$ would be a wrong way to say this, since that group has determinant $+1$ only.

Comment: Clearly all invertible matrices with integer entries must have determinant 1 or -1..

Comment: @Jacob $2I$ is invertible, its inverse is just not integral.

Comment: But general linear group over integers consists of all those matrices whose inverse also have integer entries..

Comment: @Jacob A matrix $A$ over a ring $R$ is invertible iff its determinant is *invertible in $R$*. If $R=\Bbb Z$, the units of $\Bbb Z$ are $1,-1$.

Comment: Yes but then the inverse has integer entries again in this case..

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Yes.  And this means Cohen's wording is correct.  And now that I think of it, there is another excellent reason not to use $SL_N(\Bbb{Z})$:  That implies a determinaant of $+1$. I will correct the answer for that.

Comment: Just because an integral matrix is invertible (as an integral matrix) if and only if its determinant is $\pm 1$ does not mean the theorem *can't* be true using ${\rm SL}_n$. In fact, for $n \geq 2$ the theorem *is* true using ${\rm SL}_n$ rather than ${\rm GL}_n$.